# Quitar unos caracteres en Campo de Consulta con linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

Se necesita quitar los siguientes caracteres de un Campo;

> 0.5 s,
>   0.5s,
>   0.5 S,
>   0.5S,

de una columna de una tabla donde solo se necesita el valor numérico;

Mi consulta que cree con linq la paso asi;

```
        var  ListResult = (from e in listPuerto
                          select new PuertoDto {
                               ID = e.ID,
                               valor = e.valor.Replace('S', ' ');
                             }
```

como podria realizar esto para que no solo me tome el reemplazo de un solo carácter si no de los caracteres 's' minuscula, 'S' mayuscula, ' ' y espacio vacío todo incluido en la misma consulta?

Comment: podes hacer el replace() del replace() del replace ().. e.valor.Replace().Replace() etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes anidar varios `Replace()`:

```
 var  ListResult = (from e in listPuerto
                    select new PuertoDto {
                      ID = e.ID,
                      valor = e.valor.Replace("S", "").Replace("s", "").Replace(" ", "");
                    }
```